# Collection property and Projections of Criteria API (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two entities that relate to each other as "many-to-one". So one type of the entity has a collection of child entities of another type. Is it possible to retrieve that collection property with Projections? I mean smth like

criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
.add( Projections.id() )
.add( Property.forName( "name" ) )
.add( Property.forName( "childEntities" ) ));

where childEntities is a property of the type Set.

Comment: What is the ultimate end-goal of your query? What exactly do you want to retrieve?

Comment: The ultimate goal is actually to have several properties of the parent entity and a collection of child entities with several properties populated.